# Find a parameter $m$ of a second order polynomial for which the polynomial is injective on a given interval.

Tags: functions, polynomials

I am given the function:

$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$ f(x)=x^2-mx+2$

$ m \in \mathbb{R}$

And I am asked to find $m \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the function is injective on the interval $[-1, 1]$. Here is my though process:

Since the function is a second order polynomial, that means that for the function to be injective (that is, any parallel to the $Ox$ axis would cut the function in at most one point on the interval $[-1, 1]$) then the minimum point of the graph (minimum since the coefficient of the term $x^2$ is $1>0$) must have its $x$ coordinate either *before* or *after* the interval $[-1, 1]$. That would make the function on the interval $[-1, 1]$ either strictly increasing or decreasing and since the function is continuous, it would be injective on the interval. Also, if you would place the minimum somewhere inside the interval, you could cut the function in $2$ places with a parallel to the $Ox$ axis in the given interval. Since the minimum point has the coordinates:

$V( -\dfrac{b}{2a}, -\dfrac{\Delta}{4a} )$

That means that we must have:

$-\dfrac{b}{2a} \le -1$    or

$-\dfrac{b}{2a} \ge 1$

That means:

$m \le -2$ or

$m \ge 2$.

So I concluded that $m \in (- \infty, -2 ] \cup [2, \infty)$.

The problem is, this answer is wrong. The textbook says so but I was not given an explanation. I think I have to also consider the $y$ value of the minimum point, but I do not see how placing the $x$ value of $V$ in that interval could keep the function injective, regardless of how low/high the $y$ value would be.

Comment: The correct answer should rather be $m\in (-\infty,-2]\cup [2,\infty)$.How does the textbook mange to say that your answer is wrong without telling you what s the presumably correct answer?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It's not exactly a textbook, it's just a bunch of exercises with multiple choice answers. Anyway, my answer seems to be correct then.

Comment: As I wrote (and as *Dr Zafar* did in their answer), your answer is not *completely* correct because of how infiniteis are treated. I'd still be interested how you determine that your answer (or its mild correction) is not what the multiple choice answers suggest as correct. *We* still have no idea what the bunch of exercises considers as correct or potentially correct answer

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oops, that was my bad. I didn't even notice the brackets. Well, this exercise has 5 total possible answers: A, B, C, D and E. A, B, C are clearly wrong, no need to discuss them. Then my answer (or the corrected version of my answer) is the D option and E says "Other answer". The correct choice according to that file is E, so other answer. Maybe it's just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tthe position of the max/min of the quadratic $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ is $x_0=-\frac{B}{2A}$. If The function has to be one to one (injective) fo $x \in [a,b]$ it has to either monotonically increase or decrease in $[a,b]$, then $x_0=\le a ~or~ x_0 \ge b.$
So here $$x_0=-m/2 \le -1 ~or~ x_0=-m/2 \ge 1 \implies m \in (-\infty, 2] \cup [2, \infty).$$ Remarkably, here $\Delta=B^2-4AC$ does not play any role here.